# /public/img/ folder not acceping new assets in Go-compiled web app

Tags: go, docker, gogs

I downloaded a binary via docker for the Gogs project (https://github.com/gogits/gogs), set it up (via `docker pull gogs/gogs`) and the server works as expected. Now I'm trying to customize the html a bit to look consistent with our company's other tools. When looking at deployed project, the assets of interest are in the following directories:

```
public/img/*.png
public/css/*.css
templates/*.tmpl
```

When I update the `css`, changes take effect right away, when I update `tmpl`, I need a container restart (implying that html is generated at server start time), when I update anything in `public/img/` directory, however, I can't seem to get those assets used at all and I'm clueless about what's happening since most web servers/frameworks treat `public/img/` as a static directory with all of its contents publicly visible by default.

Here is what I've tried so far and the outcomes:

**Action**: copied a new favicon image (my_favicon.png) into `public/img/` and changed `/templates/base/head.html` to point to it (/img/my_favicon.png) instead of the original (/img/favicon.png), left original untouched and restarted the container.
**Result**: page loads with broken image icon, DOM inspector says that it's pointing to /img/my_favicon.png but doesn't show the image, going to that URL directly doesn't show the image either.

**Action**: change .tmpl back to point to original image (/img/favicon.png), overwrite original with the new image. I tried this with the main lg-gogs.png logo too.
**Result**: page loads with broken image icon just like before.

A grep search for image name revealed that only the .tmpl I modified and config.codekit are mentioning it (and I'm not at all familiar with CodeKit, but the instructions claim that it's only relevant for git, not me, and to leave the file alone, although it seems to profile names and sizes of all images - however I don't see anything else on the server reference this codekit file).

I have no idea why changes to css and tmpl work fine, but images cause this unexpected result. Does anyone have an idea of what's going on, why the server isn't accepting the images?

Comment: Are you running in Docker? If so, what image are you using and how have you made your changes - by building your own image, or running a container and manually copying files?

Comment: Yes running in docker via the gogs/gogs  (latest image), using the pull command on line 2 of the post, so it's building the image. Later, to edit files, I've copied the /app/gogs directory out of docker, update it locally then copy it back into docker since the container itself has no text editor.

Comment: @AlexanderTsepkov It worked for me, but I've not edited any templates. I just overwrite the favicon.png and worked fine. The problem may be with the edits you did. Try updating your gogs which may fix your problem.